# Cache related ActiveRecord objects for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to select a collection of ActiveRecord objects and their `belongs_to` related object with a single query done. I.e. after calling

```
products = Product.joins(:image).limit(10)
```

and while iterating over `products`, I want that `product.image` didn't cause another query to the DB, but it had that `image` attribute already populated with `Image` instance cached from previous query instead.

How do I construct params for `select`, so that it selected all attributes needed to populate related objects? Or maybe I am looking in a wrong direction and there's some other way to reduce these unnecessary queries on each iteration:

```
Image Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 270783 LIMIT 1
Image Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 121344 LIMIT 1
Image Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 196239 LIMIT 1
Image Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 91194 LIMIT 1 
Image Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 116278 LIMIT 1
Image Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 117207 LIMIT 1
Image Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 244471 LIMIT 1
Image Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 239287 LIMIT 1
Image Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 15124 LIMIT 1 
Image Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = 186670 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called "eager loading". And all you have to do is change your `.joins(:image)` to `.includes(:image)` to get eager loading.

```
products = Product.includes(:image).limit(10)
```

See also the [Rails Guide on Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Well, almost, because I thought it can be done with one query not two, but that's not important.